# How can I randomize an array while keeping its elements grouped together?

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering how I could display these 2 array values at random. I tried to make the random but failed. Here are my files:

```
<?php 
$names=file('name.txt');
$fileArray = array_values(array_filter($names, "trim"));
$randomText = $fileArray[0];
$randomText .= $fileArray[1];
?> 
<h1>Test: <?php echo $randomText; ?></h1>
```

name.txt

```
Alim
Qureshi

Test2
TestTwo

Test3
TestThree

Test4
TestFour

Test5
TestFive
```

I want it to display the strings in name.txt at random, but to keep the sets of strings like "Test2 TestTwo" together so that they will be displayed at the same time. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `array_rand()`?!

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, but I do not know how to add it to this code :/ I've tried but it got me a HTTP ERROR 500 because I did it wrong

Comment: It seems like you can reduce your first two code lines to: `$names = file("name.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);` and then you can chunk your array into groups of 2, e.g. `$names = array_chunk($names, 2);`. After that as I already said you get your random key with `array_rand()`, e.g. `$key = array_rand($names);`. At the end just print out the random result: `echo implode("<br />", $names[$key]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get your values in an array you can use `array_chunk` to split it into two-item sub-arrays so that the two pieces you want can stay together when it's randomized. Then just `shuffle` it before you output.

```
$names = file('name.txt');
$fileArray = array_values(array_filter($names, "trim"));
$fileArray = array_chunk($fileArray, 2);
shuffle($fileArray);

foreach ($fileArray as $chunk) {
    $randomText = $chunk[0];
    $randomText .= $chunk[1];   
    echo $randomText . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways using `array_chunk()` so that the two stay matched:

```
$names = array_chunk($names, 2);
$rand  = $names[array_rand($names)];
echo $rand[0] . $rand[1];
```

Or:

```
$names = array_chunk($names, 2);
shuffle($names);
echo $names[0][0] . $names[0][1];
```